# need to Help query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**table :  `patient`**

```
create table patient ( patientid int,   admitdate date ,  status int  , guid int ,flag int)
insert into patient (patientid,admitdate,status,guid,flag)
values
(1,'2013--09-25', 1 ,10,1),
(1,'2014--03-25', 1 ,11,2),
(1,'2014--04-09', 1 ,12,3),
(1,'2015--01-22', 1 ,13,4),
(2,'2015--12-13', 1 ,14,5),
(2,'2014--10-10', 1 ,15,6),
(3,'2015--10-11', 1 ,16,7),
(3,'2015--12-27', 1 ,17,8),
(3,'2015--01-01', 6 ,18,9),
(4,'2011--01-01', 1 ,19,10),
(4,'2011--01-01', 1 ,20,11)
```

**table2: `patientstatus`**

```
create table patientstatus ( patientid int , startdate date ,  status int ,guid int,check int)
insert into patientstatus (patientid ,startdate ,status ,guid,check)
values
(1 ,'2013-10-02',2,50,20),
(1 ,'2014-04-09',2,51,21),
(1 ,'2015-01-30',2,52,22),
(2 ,'2015-12-15',2,53,23),
(2 ,'2015-12-15',2,54,24),
(3 ,'2015-10-11',2,55,25),
(3 ,'2015-10-12',2,56,26),
(4 ,'2011-01-02',2,57,27),
(4 ,'2010-07-02',8,58,28)
```

both table have common column patientid.
few conditons need to satisafied to get output

1. patient table  `admitdate <= startdate`  from `patientstatus`
2. days differnce between  `admitdate` and `startdate`  and days difference must me less than equal to 30 days
   if multiple records found  in patient table then we take `min(flag)  priority value( order by flag values)`
   if multiple records found  in `patientstatus` table then we take `min(check)  priority value( order by check values)`
   this logic implement only `status=1` from `patient` and `status=2` from `patientstatus`
   remain status values no need to consider

based on above two tables I want output like below.

```
patientid  |   admitdate    | status   |    guid   |  Filter
1          |  2013-09-25   |  1       |     50    | update
1          |  2014-03-25   |  1       |     11    | insert
1          |  2014-04-09   |  1       |     51    | update
1          |  2015-01-22   |  1       |     52    | update
2          |  2015-12-13   |  1       |     53    | update
2          |  2014-10-10   |  1       |     15    | insert
3          |  2015-10-11   |  1       |     55    | update
3          |  2015-12-27   |  1       |     17    | insert
4          |  2011-01-01   |  1       |     27    | update
4          |  2011-01-01   |  1       |     20    | insert
```

I tried like below:

```
SELECT  p.patientid , p.admitdate, p.status,
        CASE WHEN datediff(day, p.admitdate, ps.startdate) < 30
             THEN 'Update'
             ELSE 'Insert'
        END AS filter, 
        CASE WHEN datediff(day, p.admitdate, ps.startdate) < 30
             THEN ps.guid
             ELSE p.guid
        END AS guid
FROM    (SELECT , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY patientid  ORDER BY flag) AS rowno
         FROM patient) AS p
OUTER   APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ps.*
               FROM   patientstatus ps
               WHERE  ps.patientid=p.patientid

                 AND  ps.startdate >= p.admitdate
                 AND  ps.status = 2
               ORDER  BY  ps.check) AS ps
WHERE   p.status = 1
  AND   p.rowno = 1
```

but above query not given expected result. please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @patient table ( patientid int,   admitdate date ,  [status] int  , [guid] int ,[flag] int)
declare @patientstatus  table ( patientid int , startdate date ,  [status] int ,[guid] int,[check] int)



insert into @patient (patientid,admitdate,[status],[guid],flag)
values
(1,'2013-09-25', 1 ,10,1),
(1,'2014-03-25', 1 ,11,2),
(1,'2014-04-09', 1 ,12,3),
(1,'2015-01-22', 1 ,13,4),
(2,'2015-12-13', 1 ,14,5),
(2,'2014-10-10', 1 ,15,6),
(3,'2015-10-11', 1 ,16,7),
(3,'2015-12-27', 1 ,17,8),
(3,'2015-01-01', 6 ,18,9),
(4,'2011-01-01', 1 ,19,10),
(4,'2011-01-01', 1 ,20,11)

insert into @patientstatus (patientid ,startdate ,[status] ,[guid],[check])
values
(1 ,'2013-10-02',2,50,20),
(1 ,'2014-04-09',2,51,21),
(1 ,'2015-01-30',2,52,22),
(2 ,'2015-12-15',2,53,23),
(2 ,'2015-12-15',2,54,24),
(3 ,'2015-10-11',2,55,25),
(3 ,'2015-10-12',2,56,26),
(4 ,'2011-01-02',2,57,27),
(4 ,'2010-07-02',8,58,28)



select distinct  p.patientid,p.admitdate,p.[status] as patient_status,
 case
    when DATEDIFF(day,p.admitdate,s.startdate) < 30 then 'Update'
    else 'Insert'
 end as filter,
 case
 when DATEDIFF(day,p.admitdate,s.startdate) < 30 then s.[guid]
    else p.[guid]
 end as [guid]

from(
select  patientid, admitdate, [status], [guid], min([flag]) as [flag]
from @patient p
where [status] = 1
group by patientid,admitdate,[status], [guid]
) AS p

inner join (
    select patientid ,startdate ,[status] ,[guid],min([check]) as [check]
    from @patientstatus
    where [status] = 2
    group by patientid ,startdate ,[status] ,[guid]
) AS s on p.patientid=s.patientid
```

Comment: Above query not given expected result
example Table:patient
patientid |admitdate    |status |  guid  |flag
1         | 2014--03-25 | 1     |  11    | 2
1         | 2014--04-09 | 1     |  12    | 3
Table:patientstatus
patientid  | startdate  | status | guid |check
1          |2014-04-09  | 2      | 51   |21
expected result is 
patientid  |   admitdate    | status   |    guid   |  Filter
1          |  2014--03-25   |  1       |     11    | insert
1          |  2014--04-09   |  1       |     51    | update

Comment: The above query is correct according to your rules.  In the example that you provided above it isnt possible that you get "insert" results since your dates are within 30 days. By your definition all records where the admit date is within 30 days of start date are flagged as "update".  that is what my query proivides.